# AND-ing multiple fields which are output of an Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a query which has multiple fields . I am trying to apply the AND operator to the results of column None, Read & Write and produce group by the User. .I am trying this in Oracle

Is there a way I can user some aggregate function and get the result ?

Please help

```
Col,    User    Priv   CombPriv inheri None Read Write
Col 1   User1   R/W/S   R/W/S   NONE    0   1    1
Col 2   User1   R/W/S   R/W/S   NONE    0   1    1
Col 3   User1   R/W/S   R/W/S   NONE    0   1    1
Col 4   User1   NONE    NONE    NONE    1   0    0
Col 5   User1   R/W/S   R/W/S   NONE    0   1    1
Col 6   User1   NONE    NONE    NONE    1   0    0
Col 7   User1   R/W/S   R/W/S   NONE    0   1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own aggregate "bitand" function:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm#CECEFH

An example:

```
create type BitAnd_agg as object
(
  my_result NUMBER, 

  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT BitAnd_agg) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT BitAnd_agg, value IN number) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN BitAnd_agg, returnValue OUT number, flags IN number) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT BitAnd_agg, ctx2 IN BitAnd_agg) return number
);
/

create or replace 
type body BitAnd_agg is 
  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT BitAnd_agg) 
  return number is 
  begin
    sctx := BitAnd_agg( -1 );
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT BitAnd_agg, value IN number) return number is
  begin
     self.my_result := bitand( self.my_result, value );
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN BitAnd_agg, 
      returnValue OUT number, flags IN number) return number is
  begin
     returnValue := self.my_result;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;

  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT BitAnd_agg, ctx2 IN BitAnd_agg) return number is
  begin
    self.my_result := bitand( self.my_result, ctx2.my_result );
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  end;
end;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BitAndAgg (input NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER 
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING BitAnd_agg;
/
```

And a test:

```
CREATE TABLE tab123(
   us_er varchar2( 10 ),
   rd number,
   wr number
);

INSERT INTO tab123 VALUES( 'user 1', bin_to_num( 1,0,1,1), bin_to_num( 1,1,1,1)  );
INSERT INTO tab123 VALUES( 'user 1', bin_to_num( 0,1,1,1), bin_to_num( 1,0,1,0)  );
INSERT INTO tab123 VALUES( 'user 1', bin_to_num( 1,1,1,0), bin_to_num( 1,1,0,1)  );
INSERT INTO tab123 VALUES( 'user 2', bin_to_num( 1,0,1,1), bin_to_num( 0,1,0,0)  );
INSERT INTO tab123 VALUES( 'user 2', bin_to_num( 1,1,0,1), bin_to_num( 1,1,0,0)  );
INSERT INTO tab123 VALUES( 'user 2', bin_to_num( 0,1,0,1), bin_to_num( 1,1,1,1)  );
commit;

select us_er, BitAndAgg( rd ), BitAndAgg( wr )
from tab123
group by us_er;

US_ER      BITANDAGG(RD) BITANDAGG(WR)
---------- ------------- -------------
user 1                 2             8 
user 2                 1             4
```